# Обойти блокировку домена в hosts-файле в PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, dns, hosts

Подскажите пожалуйста. Возможно в php curl использовать сторонний DNS-сервер игнорируя запись в hosts-файле?
Ситуация такая. В hosts-файле должен быть заблокирован домен, но при этом скрипт на php должен иметь возможность с этого домена загружать файлы.

Comment: Можно сделать костыль из стороннего "шлюза", который будет ходить к домену, а php-скрипт будет ходить к этому "шлюзу".

Comment: В моем случае второй шлюз совсем не вариант. Хотелось бы это реализовать с помощью скрипта.

Comment: Силами php-скриптов, без маршрутизации в любом ее виде, думаю - это невозможно.

Comment: если ваш домен единственный висит на ип-адресе, то можете ходить без домена

Comment: `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` это можете воткнуть, возможно, будет работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пишите: "Игнорируя запись в hosts-файле". Имеется ввиду, что в hosts прописано что-то вроде:

```
127.0.0.1   <domen>
```

При условии PHP 8.1 и libcurl 7.62+ есть DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH). Погуглите, ну или почитайте тут - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85_HTTPS

Например, пишем в hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       2ip.ru
```

Пишем код:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://2ip.ru");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36h'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if (!($res = curl_exec($ch))) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $res;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Получаем по 127.0.0.1 свою ошибку (ну в моем случае, так как никто 443 на 127.0.0.1 не пытается слушать):

```
OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 2ip.ru:443
```

Добавляем публичный DNS сервер от OpenDNS:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://2ip.ru");
// Получаем DNS по HTTPS от публичного сервиса OpenDNS, в обход hosts:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DOH_URL, 'https://doh.opendns.com/dns-query');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36h'

));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if (!($res = curl_exec($ch))) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $res;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Сработало, получили свой IP от 2ip.ru:

```
...
<br>
<br>
IP: 95.31.XXX.XXX<br>
</center>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало как нужно.

Comment: странно что этого параметра нет на странице https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тоже для себя подчерпнул полезную информацию!

Comment: @Jean-Claude это так, параметра в мануале нет, но было в анонсе 8.1 (сейчас ищется в поисковых запросах, но получаю 403 при переходе): "What's New in PHP 8.1? | Zend by Perforce
zend.com›blog/php-8-1
PHP 8.1 is the first minor release in the PHP 8 series, and comes with its own new features and deprecations. Let's see what's in store for you early adopters. ... Once set, cURL will use the provided DoH provider for all DNS lookups it performs..."

Comment: да, в анонсе восьмерки есть и на сайте php.net